# Xcode 9 bot add server to team error repeatedly

Tags: xcode, continuous-integration, bots, xcode-bots

I am running Xcode 9.1 on a mac with Xcode Server.  We have it setup to run our bots but every time a bot is created when it gets to the tab that says `signing` we always see this error...

[image]

Every time I click `Add Server to Team` and it adds it and moves on but the next time I set up a bot the same thing occurs.

My issue is with people who are not admins then can't click on the button so I need to make the bots for them.  Is there a way around this? Am I missing something/doing it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be something stupid but will leave it here in case someone else experiences it.  Another one of my teammates had re-built key/cert pair and had never re-built the `provision` for it.  So we were still using the old on the server.  Once I added the new one that problem went away

Comment: Hey can you elaborate more your answer? I'm having the same issue and XCode manages my signing automatically so what should I do?

Comment: For distribution there should only be 1 key for an enterprise account.  That is the problem I was facing.  Someone had rebuilt the distribution key/cert and didn’t tell me.  So I got the new .p12 file added it to the Xcode server keychain and the problem went away.  Does that help at all?

Comment: Yes, it does! Thanks for coming back with explanation.